# Parse.com batch save from client (saveAll) timing out

Tags: javascript, api, parse-platform, save

I have a bunch of Parse objects (Can be as high as 200) that need to be updated with a common field set to a common (short) string value.  I tried using a loop with save on each one, but then it spiked my API usage beyond the limit as you can imagine when there were hundreds of them.

So, I looked into how to use the saveAll to do a batch from the Javascript client.  I got the code itself working fine and it is trying to update all of the files as expected. Now, the problem with this appears to be that it is doing a batch of PUT's inside a single batch POST to https://api.parse.com/1/batch and while it is treating this as a single HTTP operation from the client, the parse.com servers treat this as a single operation in terms of the timeout limit.

If I have more than about 5 files in the batch it will time out (Giving an error 124) since for some reason each individual save in the batch appears to take ~3 seconds according to chrome's network browser.  How can a single save take so long?

Also, this begs the question of why it is timing out at all since each save should be a separate API call (As shown in the requests internal to the batch operation).  Since I am running this batch save from the client, shouldn't there be no timeout limits anyhow as is the case in cloud code (15 seconds there)?

Can someone help me understand this?  It is a huge bottleneck and I cannot figure out any other workaround.  Seems like saving a batch of 5+ objects (With only a single string field that is dirty) shouldn't be so arduous!

Answer (score 0):

Since the objects are all being updated with the same string to the same field have you considered using a collection? As the docs say you can create a new subclass using either a model class, or a particular Parse.Query. The code to update is simplistic:

```
collection.reset([
  {"name": "Hawk"},
  {"name": "Jane"}
]);
```

https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#collections

Comment: I looked into this and it looks like one cannot actually save the objects in a collection as a batch into the backend by using the reset object.  This apparently only modifies the collection on the client side.  Check this out: https://www.parse.com/questions/can-you-save-a-collection-all-at-once-something-like-collectionsave.